# Referencing outer query's tables in a subquery

Tags: sql, mysql

Is it possible to reference an outer query in a subquery with MySQL? I know there are *some* cases where this is possible:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.date = (
    SELECT MAX(date)
    FROM table t2
    WHERE t2.id = t1.id
);
```

But I'm wondering if something like this could work:

```
SELECT u.username, c._postCount
FROM User u
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT p.user, COUNT(*) AS _postCount
    FROM Posting p
    --# This is the reference I would need:
    WHERE p.user = u.id
    GROUP BY p.user
) c ON c.user = u.id
WHERE u.joinDate < '2009-10-10';
```

I know I could achieve the same using a `GROUP BY` or by pulling the outer `WHERE` clause into the sub-query, but I need this for automatic SQL generation and cannot use either alternative for various other reasons.

**UPDATE**: Sorry, the question led to some confusion: The first query is just a working example, to demonstrate what I *don't* need.

**UPDATE 2**: I need both u.id = p.user comparisons: The first counts users that joined before '2009-10-10', while the other one is a join condition that associates table rows correctly.

Comment: why the update 2? sql will parse the derived table 'c' and get a complete list of all user ids and their post counts. the join `ON c.user = u.id` will then only return users who satisfy the joinDate constraint on `u`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

i think that won't work, because you're referencing your derived table 'c' as part of a join.

however,  you could just take out the `WHERE p.user = u.id` though and replace with a `GROUP BY p.user` in the derived table, because the `ON c.user = u.id` will have the same effect.

Comment: Thx for the answer. But your query would do something else: It would count all users regardless of join date. *edit*: sorry, looks like I had forgotten the inner group by

Comment: What if the subquery needed some different (non-`id`) column from the `user` table to do the counting?

Answer (score 29):

Isn't this what you're after?

```
SELECT u.username, c._postCount
FROM User u
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT p.user, COUNT(*) AS _postCount
    FROM Posting p
    GROUP BY p.user    
) c ON c.user = u.id
WHERE u.joinDate < '2009-10-10';
```

The reason this will work is that the nature of the join itself will filter on user. You don't need to have a WHERE clause explictly filtering on user.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to reference an outer query in a subquery with MySQL?

**Yes, it is definitely possible.** MySQL 8.0.14 and above:

> [13.2.11.9 Lateral Derived Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html)
>
> A derived table cannot normally refer to (depend on) columns of preceding tables in the same FROM clause. **As of MySQL 8.0.14, a derived table may be defined as a lateral derived table to specify that such references are permitted.**

```
SELECT u.username, c._postCount
FROM User u,
LATERAL (
    SELECT p.user, COUNT(*) AS _postCount
    FROM Posting p
    --# This is the reference I would need:
    WHERE p.user = u.id  
    GROUP BY p.user
) c
WHERE u.joinDate < '2009-10-10';
```

And minified version(removing unnecessary grouping):

```
SELECT u.username, c._postCount
FROM User u,
LATERAL (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS _postCount
    FROM Posting p
    WHERE p.user = u.id  
) c
WHERE u.joinDate < '2009-10-10';
```

Related reading: [CROSS/OUTER APPLY in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54467105/5070879)

Answer (score 2):

This solution is for postgresql.
You could use **LATERAL JOIN** which is available in postgresql. Here is how you could use it in your query.

```
SELECT u.username, c._postCount
FROM User u
INNER JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT p.user, COUNT(*) AS _postCount
    FROM Posting p
    WHERE p.user = u.id
    GROUP BY p.user
) c ON c.user = u.id
WHERE u.joinDate < '2009-10-10';
```

Here is a reference you could use. https://medium.com/kkempin/postgresqls-lateral-join-bfd6bd0199df

Comment: "You could use LATERAL JOIN which is available in postgresql" - how does this help in MySQL?

Comment: For all of us arriving from Google where this question matched 90% of our question except for platform.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably better:

```
SELECT u.username,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Posting WHERE user = u.id) as _postCount
FROM User u WHERE u.joinDate < '2009-10-10';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it to expand on the accepted answer

```
SELECT u.username, c._postCount
FROM User u
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT p.user, COUNT(*) AS _postCount
    FROM Posting p
    --# This is the reference I would need:
    --WHERE p.user = u.id ####REMOVE THIS####
    GROUP BY p.user
) c ON c.user = u.id
WHERE u.joinDate < '2009-10-10'
AND c.user = u.id -- ####ADD THIS####
```

Answer (score -1):

This would work fine

```
SELECT u.id as userid,u.username, c._postCount
FROM User u
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT p.user, COUNT(*) AS _postCount
    FROM Posting p
    --# This is the reference I would need:
    WHERE p.user = userid
    GROUP BY p.user
) c ON c.user = u.id
WHERE u.joinDate < '2009-10-10';
```