# Correlated subquery in sql to solve below question

Tags: sql

I got an assignment, I could not fix it, can anybody help me:

> Use a correlated subquery to return one row per customer, representing the customer’s most current order (the one with the latest date) with amount of sales tax greater than 100 dollars. Each row should include these four columns:EmailAddress, OrderID, OrderDate, and TaxAmount.

```
SELECT c.EmailAddress, o.TaxAmount, o.OrderDate, o.OrderID, o.CustomerID
FROM Customers AS c, Orders AS o
WHERE o.TaxAmount >100
```

Customers Table:

```
 [CustomerID]
  ,[EmailAddress]
  ,[Password]
  ,[FirstName]
  ,[LastName]
  ,[ShippingAddressID]
  ,[BillingAddressID]
```

and Orders table has the following columns:

```
 [OrderID]
  ,[CustomerID]
  ,[OrderDate]
  ,[ShipAmount]
  ,[TaxAmount]
  ,[ShipDate]
  ,[ShipAddressID]
  ,[CardType]
  ,[CardNumber]
  ,[CardExpires]
  ,[BillingAddressID]
```

Comment: What have you tried, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Tip: the correlated subquery would find `MAX(OrderDate)` in all rows `WHERE CustomerID = c.CustomerID`

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: can you post full answer @AlexLarionov

Comment: @CodeOnly I won't, because your assignment in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select EmailAddress, OrderID, OrderDate, TaxAmount
from Customers cus
 inner join Orders ord
  on ord.customerid = cus.customerid
where ord.orderdate = (select max(orderdate) 
                       from orders ord_
                       where ord_.customerid = ord.customerid
                        and ord_.taxamount > 100)
```

Comment: The inner query refers to the external one in the where clause (`where ord_.customerid = ord.customerid`), which is not possible In SQL. For instance, see this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645485/referencing-outer-querys-tables-in-a-subquery).

Comment: That is how correlated sub queries work. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery#